# Can't push to Github or Bitbucket

Tags: git, curl, github, bitbucket, git-push

I'm getting this really weird error when trying to push changes to a repo hosted on Github. I thought it was a Github issue so I moved the repo to Bitbucket but am still getting the same error. Some guidance would be appreciated on how to fix this.

NOTE: `clone` and `pull` work just fine. `push` however causes issues.

```
> git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 352 bytes | 352.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Have a look here confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-push-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-779171796.ht

Comment: @Christoph thanks for the link. I already read that. The size I'm trying to push is very small (352 bytes) and there's no proxy set either.

Comment: Try git push origin. If the remote is called origin... if this does not help show the result of git remote show origin.

Comment: @Christoph I have `push.default` set to `upstream`. But even running it with `git push origin master` gives the same error.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Christoph Umm. No.

Comment: What does `git remote show origin` say?

Answer (score 0):

For my case errno 54, I remove my git proxy with

`git config --global --unset https.proxy`

It works.